# QQ plot look approximately normal?

Tags: normality-assumption, qq-plot

It looks approximately normal to me. But it also kind of seems to be a little bit skewed cause of the points popping out between -3 and -1. This QQ plot is for an anova, but does the central limit theorem also apply here? I have over 1000 observations.

[image]

Comment: In any given situation you can't depend on the central limit theorem in any way unless you are OK with calculations being in error by a certain amount.  What are you doing that needs normality?  Can't you use a semiparametric or nonparametric method?  And normality assessments are too subjective.  We need to make better use of Bayesian models that have "non-normality" parameters in them.

Comment: @mdewey Its upper tail is a little bit *heavier* than a Normal distribution.  Overall, this plot shows positive skewness, but it's not terribly strong.

Comment: @whuber right, I deleted my misleading comment.

Comment: @FrankHarrell is correct, it depends on what you are doing, which is apparently "ANOVA on N > 1000", but that's uninformative -- given the _kind_ of data at hand, are you expecting some positive skewness, as shown here? If so, then the amount seems reasonable. If not, then why do you still get some?

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear why you are testing for normality ... you say for an anova with more than 1000 observations, you could avoid the need for normality by complementing the standard analysis with bootstrapping. Probably, the results should differ only by little.

But as for the qq-plot, observe that especially in the lower part of the plot, the plotted points lay consistently above the indicated confidence band, so there is some   evidence against a normal distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with everything said by @kjetil b halvorsen, as well as @Frank Harrell @whuber in the comments. Particularly, I agree that with the sentiment that if the researcher believes (for whatever reason) that the normality assumption is invalid for a particular application, something like bootstrapping or Bayesian methods should be used.

This being said, I believe it should be emphasized that [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) (or more specifically the [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test)) is quite robust to the assumption of normality. For an accessible review and discussion of this topic I recommend Blanca Mena et al. (2017).

**References**

Blanca Mena, M. J., Alarcón Postigo, R., Arnau Gras, J., Bono Cabré, R., & Bendayan, R. (2017). Non-normal data: Is ANOVA still a valid option?. Psicothema, 2017, vol. 29, num. 4, p. 552-557.